# Cross compile for arm in scientific linux

Tags: c, linux, arm, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I am running yum install

```
gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

on my machine, but it says:

```
No package gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi available.
```

Please help me to set up cross compilation tool for arm in scientfic linux. 
As I am naive in this, please tell me step by step process.

Comment: which linux system you are using ?\

Comment: try sourcery codebench. That's where I found my cross toolchain.

There's always the option of compiling GCC for arm target yourself. there are plenty of guides on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo yum install gcc-arm*` to see and if any of your interested package is in the list ... try downloading it ...

if it does not help try `sudo yum install arm*linux*` or similar searches to narrow down to the package you require

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent package on fedora derivatives (rhel, centos, etc) is `arm-linux-gnu-gcc`. It is in the gcc-arm-linux-gnu package:

`yum install gcc-arm-linux-gnu gcc-c++-arm-linux-gnu`